# Likelihood Ratio Java

Tags: java, machine-learning

I'm searching for a library or an example on how to implement in java a likelihood ratio test like in matlab.

I have two different vector of double values and want to receive a scalar value. 
Every value correspond to a feature for my machine learning algorithm so one the first vector is the training pattern and the second one a test.

Could you please help me?

On matlab i just use division on two matrix like LR= test_matrix/training_matrix

I've tryied with apache mahout but i'm not sure i'm using it correctly.
Here the code:

```
        FastByIDMap<FastByIDMap<Long>> timestamps = new FastByIDMap<>();
        Collection<Preference> prefs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        FastByIDMap<Collection<Preference>> data = new FastByIDMap<>(); //Preferecens for user0
        Preference newPrefs = new GenericPreference(0, 0, (float) -0.5);
        Preference pref = new GenericPreference(0, 1, 50);
        Preference pref2 = new GenericPreference(0, 2, 51);
        prefs.add(newPrefs);
        prefs.add(pref);
        prefs.add(pref2);
        data.put(0, prefs);
        Collection<Preference> prefs_1 = new ArrayList<>(2);
        newPrefs = new GenericPreference(1, 0, (float) -0.5);
        pref = new GenericPreference(1, 1, 50);
        pref2 = new GenericPreference(1, 2, 51);
        prefs_1.add(newPrefs);
        prefs_1.add(pref);
        prefs_1.add(pref2);
        data.put(1, prefs_1);
        GenericDataModel model = new GenericDataModel(GenericDataModel.toDataMap(data, true), timestamps);
        FastByIDMap<PreferenceArray> us = model.getRawUserData();
        System.out.println("us:"+ us.toString());
        LogLikelihoodSimilarity l = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);
        System.out.println(l.userSimilarity(0, 1));
```

In this case, user similarity alwasy return 0.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm sorry. I've added the code.

Comment: what's the framework you are using?

Comment: I'm using  apache mahout  but I think that this "Log-LikeLihood" is different from the likelihood from matlab